# What light weight container could be used in embedded linux platform

Tags: linux, containers

In my work cases, 3rd party daemon/lib will run in my embedded linux platform, those daemons/libs are really blackbox(closed source) that I don't have full control of it. I heard container technology could solve that issue. So just wonder is there any light weight container framework I can use in my embedded linux platform to well manage 3rd party daemon/lib in user space. I'm actually the newbie for that area, some advice are really appreciate!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Docker seems to be the most popular container framework. This post might be useful if you are using raspberry pi: https://byteoutalife.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/building-docker-from-source-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Another option is LXC (search for stephan graber lxc tutorials on google) which works well on ubuntu but not sure if you can get it working on your os.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [systemd-nspawn](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) if you have the option of running systemd on that machine.

Alternativelly a good option would be to run [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/drvlxc.html) with LXC support.